# Erro ao Enviar Mensagem com venom js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, puppeteer

Estou utilizando o venom.js para envio de mensagens pelo whatsapp, ele funciona perfeitamente, desde que o cliente envie a primeira interação, ou seja quando eu tento enviar algum texto básico, no primeiro momento ele envia, mas na segunda vez que rodo o código ele, aparece um erro de Promise no puppeteer, já procurei na internet algo que fale a respeito mas sem êxito; Tentei utilizar o Sulla, mas o problema é o mesmo, Segue o código e logo abaixo o erro, desde já agradeço ao pessoal do fórum, por ceder o valioso tempo para nos responder;

```
const venom = require('venom-bot');

venom.create().then((client) => start(client));

async function start(client) {
// Send basic text
  await client
    .sendText('5531999999999@c.us', 'Olá Sou um Robô!')
    .then((result) => {
        console.log('Result: ', result.status);        
    })
    .catch((erro) => {
        console.error('Error no Processo: ', erro.status); //return object error
    });
}
```

Tentei com o async/await ou sem, mas só funciona uma vez, talvez seja um detalhe, mas preciso que funcione constantemente, pois irei colocar dados de um setInterval e todas vez que outra api receber uma resposta irá chamar o VenomJs para que possa enviar para o Whatsapp;

```
(node:5420) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: WAPI is not defined
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:3:45
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (C:\wamp64\www\apiplug\desktop_dev\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:221:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (C:\wamp64\www\apiplug\desktop_dev\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:110:16)
(node:5420) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use 
the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5420) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score -1):

Eu tentei por diversas vezes até que resolvi trabalhar com outro framework, whatsapp-web.js, na época funcionou bem, inclusive ele trabalha como uma API diferente do Venon, consegui enviar mensagens sem iteração;
Entra no GuitHub, dá uma olhada na documentação:
https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/

Answer (score -1):

Parece que este bug foi resolvido neste [commit](https://github.com/orkestral/venom/commit/18281d37bd26197b0df7621cad0512fc845fc3a4).

A versão até o momento ainda não foi lançada oficialmente. Para testar o *Nightly releases* da [versão 3.1.5-alpha.0 **2021-09-09**](https://github.com/orkestral/venom/compare/v3.1.4...v3.1.5-alpha.0) só executar

```
npm i --save https://github.com/orkestral/venom/releases/download/nightly/venom-bot-nightly.tgz
```

Como ainda é uma versão Alpha, recomendo que teste exaustivamente.

Answer (score -1):

```
const venom = require('venom-bot');

function Msg(props){

venom.create().then((client) => start(client));

function start(client) {
// Send basic text
const telefoneTratado = props.telefone[0]+'@c.us';
  client
    .sendText(telefoneTratado, props.suamensagem)
    .then((result) => {
        console.log('Result: ', result.status); 
        process.exit(1);       
    })
    .catch((erro) => {
        console.error('Error no Processo: ', erro.status); //return object error
    });
}

};
exports.Msg = Msg;
```

Agora você pode chamar essa função exportada e criar sua api.
Quando você invocar a api, ele vai abrir o venom ( passe o QR code na primeira vez e sempre que chamar de um local novo , depois ele fica gravado ).
Você pode passar por ela numero do telefone da pessoa( no meu caso se for so um numero: const telefoneTratado = prop.stelefone[0]+'@c.us'; )
Tambem pode passar mensagem, links de imagens, arquivos etc

Neste caso , não precisa de interação com o cliente, o bot abre e ja envia a mensagem. Estou utilizando desta forma aqui.
;)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).